# Angular-CLI + Electron cannot find module 'path'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, electron

I'm using Electron with Angular CLI and trying to get a relative path to my file. I'm trying to use path module for it, since it is working in main.js where electron does it's magic.

**main.js**

```
const path = require('path')
```

When I switch to app.component and import path VSCode shows no error and recognises path as module

[image]

But when I try to serve the app, webpack throws an error

```
ERROR in D:/Projects/project/src/app/app.component.ts (2,23): Cannot find module
 'path'.
```

I tried to find path module in node_modules folder and found 4 folders containing 'path', which leads me to believe that node's `require()` function used in electron's main.js is a little more complicated than loading contents of a single folder in node_modules.

So, my question is how do I import path method (and, possibly, other methods) in my components?

Comment: `path` is a core module, they don't appear in the node_modules folder and are instead compiled into the executable. Did you set the target for webpack properly (`node`)?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that with angular cli (or I haven't found a way. On of the folks from cli stated in GitHub that you can't change target, but maybe they add this functionality in the future (in regard to angular cli v 1.0.0)

Comment: Is it maybe possible to set the target manually in the webpack config?

Comment: Maybe... But where it should be located? Inside webpack folder in node_modules or in root folder of my app? If latter, then how to not screw it's work with cli? I'm confused, as you can see

Comment: In the root of your project of course. I think Angular CLI lets the webpack config default to `target: 'web'`, so you just can change it to `node`. Just test it and revert to the default, if it doesn't work.

Comment: As I found, there is a way for angular cli to generate webpack config, but after you do, cli can't be used anymore. Googling into this right now